# Preventing component updates from multiple props in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have a react/redux app which has a recharts chart which animates when data is changed.

I'm using `Redux` and most of my actions only change a single `state` property which results in a single `props` pass. However, some of my actions are now using `thunks` for some async actions and calling other actions.

For example, I might have an action `getChartData` which would be called when the user selects an axis.

```
export let getChartData = axis => dispatch => {
  // trimmed for brevity
  fetchJSON(url).then(data => {
    dispatch(dataRetrievalSuccess(data));
    dispatch(updateSelectedAxis(axis));
  }).catch(error => {
    dispatch(dataRetrievalError(error));
  });
};
```

In this example the `updateSelectedAxis` value will change a local state property responsible for displaying the currently selected axis and the `dataRetrievalSuccess` function would be responsible for passing  `props.data` to the chart.

The problem I'm trying to solve is to prevent the chart from updating when the selectedAxis props of the component change but the data hasn't.

I thought I would be able to use something like `componentWillRecieveProps` but the issue I have here with my above `thunk` example is that I get one call to `componentWillRecieveProps` when I call `dataRetrievalSuccess` which has the same data in both `this.props.data` and `nextProps.data` so I can prevent the update. However when I subsequently call `updateSelectedAxis` I don't have the `data` as part of the props as it's already changed, so I can't perform logic operations based on the two values.

I thought this was possibly an ordering issue, but even if I pack this into a single action I still get multiple setting of props.

Would I solve this issue by packaging up the data and the change of axis into a single object? 
I'm not quite sure the best way to go about this architecturally and would welcome any suggestions.

**EDIT:**
Just to expand a little, I am dispatching two actions, both which change their own bit of state which causes two renders.

I've tried writing something like this:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  if(this.dataHasChanged(nextProps)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Which almost works, but each time the data the chart shows is one render behind where it needs to be.

Comment: What about shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) ?

Comment: This single state property you mentioned consists of DATA and AXIS? In other world, in global state you have access to those variables? (and its accessible through this.props you're passing to component? Im missing that part. If you have access to those two objects you can use componentShouldUpdate function :>

Comment: @DennisStücken The problem with this is that I get two calls to this function, one with the data and one with the axis changes and I need both to work out whether I should be updating the chart animation.

Comment: @MariuszJasinski I only seem to get access to one property at a time. Two runs through the shouldComponentUpdate function one with data and the other with axis.
Neither on it's own is enough for me to know whether I should update the component. I guess combining into a single object would allow me to do this, but is this the best way?

Comment: Now I get it @dougajmcdonald. You dispatch 2 actions, and each of these two change the state (so render occurs) and you dont have access to new version of the second one. Yea definitely combine those two would help. I have one idea:

The second argument of think action is getState function. You get get the current state by calling this one and compare if the actual axis/data is different from the received one and depends on that dispatch certain actions :)

Comment: @MariuszJasinski yes that is correct (sorry if I explained it badly!) you're right with the second action being the get state function but I'm not sure if that's the best place to put that kind of logic.

Comment: Its true, it creates kind of bad "ifs" at async actions, which is bad - second thought came into my mind... Im not sure if its as bad as the previous one :D : Create property ```prevValueOfAxis``` at your store (you will have access to it through props since you told that its one big object) and determine ```shouldComponentUpdate``` based on that.. :) Of course it requires additional logic at updating... but Im out of ideas :D
Maybe just combining those two will be the best idea possible :)

Comment: Just to clarify: This "merging" isnt a bad thing IMHO. You should update your ```dataRetrievalSuccess``` to accept second argument (axis), and create a reducer which will update state as you need - thanks to that you will have one render instead of two :)

Comment: @MariuszJasinski that's what I'm trying to get to grips with architecturally, I want to try to keep my functions clean and responsible for a single update, so having one user action trigger one massive `action` which does a lot seems wrong to me. I was hoping to fire several smaller actions but that's what's led me here.

Comment: Ye I get it, its good principle :) So I wont be able to help you Im afraid :) But good luck!

Comment: @dougajmcdonald do this: create maps dataUpdatesSeen and axisUpdatesSeen in your component's state. When your thunk issues the data update and axis update actions together, give them the same id. If you issue only one action, give it an id. In shouldComponentUpdate, check if there are any ids that exist in both maps and map to true in both maps - you've seen an update of both, return true! render! In componentDidUpdate, if you find such a pair of ids, remove them from the maps and update the maps in state. You won't re-render because the next shouldComponentUpdate won't see the matching pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the current State of store under action creator  using thunk (as thunk inject the state for you.) , then compare ajax response data with previous state data to dispatch new action.

```
 export let getChartData = axis => (getState, dispatch) => {
          // trimmed for brevity
          fetchJSON(url).then(data => {
           if(getState().data !== data){
            dispatch(dataRetrievalSuccess(data));
            dispatch(updateSelectedAxis(axis));
            }
          }).catch(error => {
            dispatch(dataRetrievalError(error));
          });
        };
```